# CKeditor (BASIC) standalone .js version

Tags: plugins, ckeditor

I currently have a local copy of CKeditor that I am importing/using..

```
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
```

However.. I noticed these have IMAGE and MEDIA buttons in this version... (which are not desired)

I read that the BASIC version does NOT have these options..

But when I went to the 'builder'.. and selected BASIC (no extra plug-ins added)..

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/

It gave me a huge .zip file with tons of other assets..etc..

Is there a way I can find/create a standalone CKeditor.js file.. that ONLY has BASIC plug-ins/options?

(Or somehow edit this one to remove IMAGE & MEDIA buttons from toolbar?)

WHen I went through the BUILDER.. I removed IMAGE and MEDIA options..
and then built my version and downloaded it.

I only grabbed the ckeditor.js file (form the .zip).. and uploaded it.

I now see it in the SOURCE code.. but there is no visual CKeditor toolbar displayed on the page??

Answer (score 0):

I realized the implementation need some extra code added to it:

Original:

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor.create(document.querySelector('#template_message'));
</script>
```

This is how it should be implemented:

```
<!-- NEW CKEditor Approach (Customized buttons) -->
                        <script>
                            ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#template_message' ), {
                                toolbar: {
                                    items: [
                                        'heading',
                                        '|',
                                        'bold',
                                        'italic',
                                        'link',
                                        'bulletedList',
                                        'numberedList',
                                        '|',
                                        'indent',
                                        'outdent',
                                        '|',
                                        'blockQuote',
                                        'insertTable',
                                        'undo',
                                        'redo'
                                    ]
                                },
                                language: 'en-gb',
                                table: {
                                    contentToolbar: [
                                        'tableColumn',
                                        'tableRow',
                                        'mergeTableCells'
                                    ]
                                },
                                licenseKey: '',

                            } )
                            .then( editor => {
                                window.editor = editor;




                            } )
                            .catch( error => {
                                console.error( 'Oops, something gone wrong!' );
                                console.error( 'Please, report the following error in the https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5 with the build id and the error stack trace:' );
                                console.warn( 'Build id: n4w33zuqu2d9-qrolc6ajm7ow' );
                                console.error( error );
                            } );
                        </script>
```

Hope this helps someone else as well.

Props to: Brandon!

*Love there is finally an 'editor'!!!